# What justifies the perturbative expansion in chiral perturbation theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, perturbation-theory, effective-field-theory

The Lagrangian of chiral perturbation theory is ordered following a momenta power counting scheme, having terms at leading order (which is two 2 $O(p^2)$) next to leading order ($O(p^4)$) and so on. But how do we know that terms with higher momenta power are less important? I mean, how do we know that 
$$p<1$$
so that we can make a perturbative expansion?

Comment: That's the whole spirit of low energy effective field theory... You are working at low values of p. Note that on dimensional grounds p<1 doesn't make sense, you should say p<M for some energy scale M, which for chiral perturbation theory is of order Lamda_QCD.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what application you are interested in. When discussing chiral perturbation theory it is implied that you are interested in low energy processes. If you are considering processes such as low energy (~100 MeV) pion scattering, pion decay, etc. then the typical energies involved are O(100 MeV) which is much smaller then $\Lambda_{QCD}$. This makes $p/\Lambda_{QCD}$ a good expansion parameter.

If on the other hand you were studying pion scattering at 10 GeV then chiral perturbation theory would give non-sensible results.

Answer (score 1):

Non zero quark masses break chiral symmetry. This breaking is assumed to be small enough (certainly for the up and down but also for the strange quark) to do a meaningful Taylor like expansion in it. The relevant scale to which the masses need to be compared is about 1 GeV.

It is no guarantee the series will converge but there are predictions that follow from first order terms that are consistent with experimental data.